# Create an image made up of two regions with identical means but different variances Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, image-segmentation

How can we create in python an image made up of two regions with identical means but different variances (intensities of regions created using realizations of normal laws).

I found this little code but i don't know if it's really like that :

```
  I = np.random.normal (128,10, (256, 256)); 
  Icentre = np.random.normal (128,50, (80, 80))
  I [100: 180,100: 180] = Icentre;
```

I'm working in total variation segmentation so the second part is to make a mask m corresponding well to the size of the image then test the segmentation procedure with this image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple options, one would be to just concatenate two images together. For example:

```
import numpy as np

im1 = np.random.normal(128, 10, (256, 256)) #mean of 128, std of 10
im2 = np.random.normal(128, 6, (256, 256)) #mean of 128, std of 6

# create image from both regions, shape = (512, 256)
img = np.concatenate((im1, im2))
```

In this example case the rows 0-255 would have a mean of 128 and std of 10, while rows 256-512 would have a mean of 128 and std of 6.

The code you posted above would also work. In that case you are inserting `Icentre` into `I` starting at `row=100` and `col=100` and ending at `row=180` and `col=180`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what i was looking for, you mean np.concatenat((im1,im2))

Comment: Cool, happy to help.